# Find text, Insert page break and repeat

Tags: vba, ms-word

How do I find a phrase, go to the beginning of the line the phrase is in, insert a page break, then execute the macro again.

I have attempted the following but it will not go to the following value of "Agent Name" upon subsequent execution.

```
Sub mFI()
    ' ' mFI Macro ' '
    Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
    With Selection
        .Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Forward = True
        .MatchWholeWord = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .Execute FindText:="Agent Name"
    End With
    Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
    Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1
    Selection.InsertBreak Type:=wdPageBreak, Count:=1
End Sub
```

Comment: What research have you done already to see how you can achieve those goals?

Comment: I have attempted the following but it will not go to the following value of "Agent Name" upon subsequent execution.

Sub mFI()
'
' mFI Macro
'
'
    Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
    
 
    With Selection.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Forward = True
        .MatchWholeWord = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .Execute FindText:="Agent Name"
    End With

    Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
    Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1
    Selection.InsertBreak Type:=wdPageBreak, Count:=1
End Sub

Answer (score 0):

assuming code you provided is correct, This will help you.

```
Sub mFI()
    ' ' mFI Macro ' '
    Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
    With Selection
        .Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Forward = True
        .MatchWholeWord = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .Execute FindText:="Agent Name"
    End With
    Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
    Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1
    Selection.InsertBreak Type:=wdPageBreak, Count:=1
    With Selection
        .Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Forward = True
        .MatchWholeWord = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .Execute FindText:="Agent Name"
    End With
    Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
    Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1
End Sub
```

Comment: did this solved your probelm? please tell us more if this doesn't

Answer (score 0):

IF you want to insert page break to all the occurrences of agent name you could try.

```
Sub Demo()
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "Agent Name"
        .Replacement.Text = "^m^&"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End Sub
```